# Convert a for loop to a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a `for` loop that compares a substring of each element in a list of strings to the elements in another list of strings.

```
mylist = []
for x in list1:
    mat = False
    for y in list2:
        if x[:-14] in y:
            mat = True
    if not mat:
        mylist.append(x)
```

However I would like to put it in a list comprehension (for loops aren't as concise for my tastes) But can't find a way to do it with the calculation of `mat`.

I have tried variations on:

```
 mylist = [x for x in list1 if x[:-14] in list2]
```

But this is not the same logic as the original loop.  Is there a way to reform the original for loop into list comprehension?

Comment: No, this isn't a conversion service. If you've tried this yourself and got stuck somewhere, please provide a [mcve]. Also note that not all `for` loops can become list comprehensions.

Comment: I've edited out the preface because Meta content doesn't belong in questions and people can downvote whether or not they're giving you an answer/a link to one. It's not at all *"obvious this is a question asked so it can be applied to a broader range of problems"*, **you've literally asked for your one example to be converted**, without any apparent effort on your own behalf.

Comment: Do you want me to provide links to all the other things I've tried on this site?  That's what your statement would amount to.  This is a simple question for which more effort is spent proving I tried than it would take to answer the question.  quite absurd response...I've spent minimum of probably 30 minutes searching and trying before posting

Comment: Try do this own and return here If You will have some problem :)

Comment: What @MartinP said. You don't have to provide *"links to all the other things"*, necessarily, but edited highlights of your research so far would be nice. *"I've spent minimum of probably 30 minutes"* - ooh, a whole... err, half hour? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe "A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. In fact, asking a question on Stack Overflow is the absolute last thing you ever want to do. You want to avoid it at all costs. You want to think of it as a horrible shame1 that will forever haunt you and pass down from you to your descendants. You want very much to find your answer some other way."

I guess this isn't the site I thought it was....my mistake.

Comment: Perhaps not, it is unclear what you thought it was. Try the [tour] and [help].

Comment: "Do [task] for me" posts are generally quite poorly received, as are orders to not downvote you. This is a question and answer site; if you want help, you should ask questions. (That Meta answer is pretty bad, though.)

Comment: @jonrsharpe it also is not a place to have long arguments in which you insult the other person by calling them a jerk. Quite frankly you seem to have put way more effort into putting the OP down then it took me to rephrase the question to fit SO standards. (if you think it can be improved more feel free to edit)

Comment: @user2357112 perhaps now it is better phrased?  This is not the first time someone has asked about converting a for loop into list comprehension so I figured we needed one to redirect future askers to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is written, no you cannot directly write it as a list comprehension as there is no place in a comprehension for intermediate variables like `mat`.

however, if you refactor the intermediate variable to be computed as a separate function:

```
def check_match(x, seq):
    "checks if text excluding the last 14 characters of string `x` is a substring of any elements of the list `seq`"
    mat = False
    for y in seq:
        if x[:-14] in y:
            mat = True
    return mat

mylist = []
for x in list1:
    mat = check_match(x, list2)
    if not mat:
        mylist.append(x)
```

now we can move the function call directly into the `if not` condition, also in your particular case you are applying the logic of the `any` function so you can simplify your function:

```
def check_match(x, seq):
    "checks if text excluding the last 14 characters of string `x` is a substring of any elements of the list `seq`"
    return any((x[:-14] in y) for y in seq)

mylist = []
for x in list1:
    if not check_match(x, list2):
        mylist.append(x)
```

Now that we don't have any intermediate variables, it is pretty straight forward to convert:

```
mylist = [x for x in list1 if not any((x[:-14] in y) for y in list2)]
# or if your case can't be easily refactored into a single expression just leave it as a separate function
# mylist = [x for x in list1 if not check_match(x, list2)]
```

alternatively, if you keep it as a separate function that returns `True` for the elements to **keep** and only takes the element as an argument you could then use `filter` directly:

```
def is_not_in_list2(x):
    "checks if x[:-14] is *not* a substring of any elements of `list2`"
    return not any((x[:-14] in y) for y in list2)
myiterator = filter(is_not_in_list2, list1)
# you can loop over `myiterator` once and it will be very memory efficient, or if you need it as a proper list just pass it to the list constructor
mylist = list(myiterator)
```

Comment: Friend, you read into the point of the question and provided a concise answer that includes the method to convert from the for loop to list comprehension.  I just tried it and worked great.  Faith in SO = restored!

Comment: @user3496060 I am so glad I restored your faith, since you clearly like to learn from examples I have edited your question to what I think is a good fit for SO (the original was very localized and not very likely to help future viewers)  I hope it might give you a better idea of the kind of question that will be better received so you don't lose your faith again!

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
mylist = [x for x in list1 if x[:-14] not in list2]
```

Comment: yea i tried this one before posting (found another example) and it didn't work.